# Recursive get path from multidimensional php array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have array:

```
$adm_menu_old = array (
    array( 
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Test1',
    ), 
    array( 
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Test3',
        'childrens' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 31,
                'name' => 'Test31',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 32,
                'name' => 'Test32',
                'childrens' => array(
                     array(
                        'id' => 321,
                        'name' => 'Test321',
                     ),
            ),
        )
    ), 
    array( 
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Test4',
    ), 
);
```

Say i know id value.
I need get path with all parents of this id.
For example i need get path to this element: id=321
i need get array with key name values:

```
array('Test3','Test32','Test321')
```

how  should look like recursive function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function getNames($id, $arr) {
  $result = array();
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
      if(is_array($val)) {
        if($val["id"] == $id) {
          $result[] = $val["name"];
        } elseif(!empty($val["childrens"]) && is_array($val["childrens"])) {
          $sub_res = getNames($id, $val["childrens"]);
          if(count($sub_res) > 0) {
          $result[] = $val["name"];
          $result = array_merge($result, $sub_res);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```